# seo for single ajax population

Tags: jquery, ajax, seo

I developed a little cross domains population script with query and php.

The population injects text and links but i really need some tip to implement seo on the populated div, the content dosen't change is only loaded just one time.

i'm reading a lot about it, this is a well-known limitation but....any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to make a non JS version of that page if you wish for search engines to find your content.

Comment: i know this...but it is remotely populated

Comment: Pull the data on the server and serve it as static HTML then. I'm afraid that is the only solution for now.

Comment: i use JS to perform cross domain population, there is another solution to inject html seo friendly from cross domains?